# Is it possible to turn on the bluetooth of an android device programmatically and connect with other

Tags: javascript, android, bluetooth, apk

I am trying to create an app using **Android Studio** which will turn on the bluetooth when there's an incoming call and connect to the given device's name and eventually turn off the bluetooth after the call ends. But I have less ideas about javascripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you some tips:

1.) Enable Bluetooth:

```
  mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                        BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivity(enableBtIntent);
            } 
   }
```

2.) Connect to device:

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(address);
BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice
                        .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUUID);
try{
  mBluetoothSocket.connect();
} catch (Exception e){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About turning on and off your bluetooth and connect to a device, you'll find everything that you need [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

To learn how to detect a phone call, you can follow [this tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_Phone_Call_Broadcast_Receiver__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=61&aaid=86)

Cheers !

Comment: The link you gave isn't available now. The First link !